# getting a field value from mysql through a dynamic php dropdown list and export this value to a word file

Tags: php, mysql, forms

am trying to getting a field value from mysql through a dynamic php dropdown list and export this value to a  word file

```
<?php

include_once '../includes/db_connect.php';

sec_session_start();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<TITLE>Export Awarding Fax </TITLE>
<STYLE type="text/css">
    H1 { text-align: center ;
        text-decoration: underline  }
</STYLE>
<BODY>
<h1>    FAX</h1>
<form  method="post"  >
    <?php
    // LOGIN TO DATABASE SCRIPT WRITTEN FOR MYSQLI
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "mansoura");
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " .            $mysqli->connect_error;
    }
    // END OF LOGIN TO DB SCRIPT

    $query_ak='SELECT  DISTINCT id,CompanyName,SupplierFax1 FROM suppliers';
    $result = $mysqli->query($query_ak);
    ?>
    <form name="forms" action="<?php //echo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post"">
    <!--<form name="forms" action="awarding_fax.php" method="post"">   -->
    <select name="go" >

               <?php  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            //    <?php while ($row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $id = $row["id"];
                   $CompanyName = $row["CompanyName"];
                  // $CompanyName= mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_POST['go']));

                    echo '<option value="' . "Company Name : " . $row['CompanyName'] . "Fax No : " . $row['SupplierFax1'] . '">' . "Company Name : " . $row['CompanyName'] . " Fax No : " . $row['SupplierFax1'] . '</option>';
                   echo "$CompanyName";
                }

                  ?>


    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Export"  name="go"/>
</form>



</body>
</html>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<STYLE type="text/css">
    H2{ text-decoration: underline}
    P.mypar {text-align: justify
    margin: 0 0 10px}
</STYLE>
<BODY>




Company Name : <?php echo "$CompanyName"; ?>
<h2> SUBJECT:..............  </h2>
<P class="mypar"> Reference to our...


<?php
if(isset($_POST['go'])){
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.msword");
    header("Expires: 0");//no-cache
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");//no-cache
    header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=sampleword.doc");

}
echo "<html>";
echo "$doc_body";
echo "$CompanyName";
echo "</html>";
```

The above code  gives me the dynamic drop down list  but the value of field CompanyName is always the last value in database
besides the submit button doesn't seems  to be working as should be  ( can't change value in word  file )

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to `remove` this `form` tag from your code

```
<form name="forms" action="<?php //echo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post"">
```

Because there is `two form` in your code on which one `form tag` is not closed.

**Second thing**

I don't you have create any function of name

```
sec_session_start();
```

in your code or it may be

```
session_start();
```

Comment: i've deleted the second line form and commenting sec_session_start();  has no effect

Comment: and you remove form element??

Comment: the error  is echo "$CompanyName";   gives  me the last value  in the db

Comment: also  the submit button  doesn't work  , it gives me the first value  in word file